# docker windows image hang when running without tty parameter

Tags: windows, docker, server-core

We are containerize a inhouse .NET 4.7 console app using Windows docker image `mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019`.

`docker run my-image` is hang when running however `docker run -t my-image` is working fine.

```
dockerfile:
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
    COPY c:/myapp/ ./myapp/
    RUN c:\windows\system32\regsvr32.exe /s c:\myapp\somedll.dll
    RUN "c:\myapp\myapp.exe" mydata.csv
```

Any idea please?

Comment: It doesn't "hang" it just doesn't show any output.
You can run it with "-d" to run it detached and later you can view the logs of this container.

Comment: it shows the output in few second and then stop showing anything. the run never ends.

Comment: Can you provide an example Dockerfile where this happens?

Comment: dockerfile added. just pull the servercore image, register a dll then run the myapp.exe.

Comment: I don't see a step in the Dockerfile that creates the binary. Also there doesn't seem to be a command for running the container, not sure what the default servercore command is since Microsoft doesn't appear to provide the Dockerfile. I don't have a Windows system to test on but the example appears to be invalid.

Comment: we just copy all bin files from c:\myapp to docker before launching c:\myapp\myapp.exe

Answer (score 0):

`docker run [image name]` command run the container and wait for it until the process ends.

with `-t` option, we can connect the current console(tty) to the container, so we can see the output.

with `-i` option, we can also use input (interactive mode).

with `-d` option, we can detach the container so it could run like a server.

Typically, use `run -d` option for server start and `run -ti` option for debugging.

I think a docker container not much different from a local process. We could run it foreground (-ti) or background (-d).

Comment: tried -`d` the container took 30min to finish. `-t` took 11s.  the app has 6 running threads. any thoughts?